# psycopg2 - Update a json column with a new key/value pair

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Let's say I have a table that has a **json** type column.

I have data like so:

```
{"Value A": 20}
```

How do I update the row and only add a key value pair to the json column of that row so it looks like this?

```
{"Value A" : 20, "Value B": 25}
```

I am using psycopg2 and PostgreSQL 14.

Comment: `update tname set datacol = datacol || '{"Value B": 25}'`

Comment: That works, please add it as an answer.

Comment: You could have avoided the question all together by reading the docs [JSON Operators/functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html).